# Results to Grid is substituting Tab for Space characters

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a need to take some values from columns and combine together separated by Tab characters.  However in SSMS when using "Results to Grid" I have discovered a strange behavior where it is substituting the Tab/`CHAR(9)` with a Space/`CHAR(32)`.  Using "Results to File" or "Results to Text" the expected behavior occurs.
Can this substitution behavior in Results to Grid be controlled?

```
PRINT 'a'+CHAR(9)+'b'
SELECT 'a'+CHAR(9)+'b'
```

Result:

```
a   b 
a b
```

Interestingly when run using `OSQL` the results are as expected, the tab remains present:

```
1> PRINT 'a'+CHAR(9)+'b'
2> go
a       b
1> SELECT 'a'+CHAR(9)+'b'
2> go

 ----
 a      b
```

Comment: Have you checked the option "Retain CR/LF...."?

Comment: Thanks - yes I have set the option "Retain CR/LF" but could not observe a difference in behavour.